# Is it possible to use hibernate native query when need to return list objects?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables (for this example, Customer and Product) to have json returned in a query, containing one field that is a list (one to many relationship)

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> products;
}
```

The hibernate  query is very complicated and uses createNativeQuery()

For a rest api returning a single Customer, I simply run a second query for the products and set the field independently

```
customerDTO.setProduct(productsForCustomer);
```

But now I am requested to build an API that returns a list of ALL customers given certain criteria - must return  `List<Customer>`

Is this even possible using nativeQuery or would I have to rewrite the query for entities using JQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended approach would be JPQL. With a native query you would have to populate the entities by processing the resultset.

I guess it depends whether your complex query is whether it's possible with JPQL

In it's simplest form that would be

```
em.createQuery("select c from Customer c join fetch c.products where c.id = :id", Customer.class).setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
```